# Parse a comma separated list of emails in Python which are of the format "Name" <email>

Tags: python, regex, email

Input (comma separated list):

```
"\"Mr ABC\" <mr@abc.com>, \"Foo, Bar\" <foo@bar.com>, mr@xyz.com"
```

Expected output (list of 2-tuples):

```
[("Mr ABC", "mr@abc.com"), ("Foo, Bar", "foo@bar.com"), ("", "mr@xyz.com")]
```

I could actually use comma splitting and then use [`email.utils.parseaddr(address)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr) until I realized that the name part can also have comma in it, like in "Foo, Bar" above.

[`email.utils.getaddresses(fieldvalues)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses) is very close to what I need but it accepts a sequence, not a comma separated string.

Comment: You could split at `>, `

Comment: There is a useful header parsing method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511371/how-do-you-extract-multiple-email-addresses-from-an-rfc-2822-mail-header-in-pyth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"(?:\s+<([^<>]+)>)?')
test_str = '"Mr ABC" <mr@abc.com>, "Foo, Bar" <foo@bar.com>, "mr@xyz.com"'
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Output: `[('Mr ABC', 'mr@abc.com'), ('Foo, Bar', 'foo@bar.com'), ('mr@xyz.com', '')]`

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/TUOdWg)

The regex matches...

- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]+)` - (Group 1) 1 or more characters other than a double quote
- `"` - a double quote

Then, an optional non-capturing group is introduced with `(?:...)?` construct: `(?:\s+<([^<>]+)>)?`. It matches...

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace characters
- `<` - an opening angle bracket
- `([^<>]+)` - (Group 2) 1 or more characters other than opening or closing angle brackets
- `>` - a closing angle bracket

The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) function gets all capture groups into a list of tuples:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

**UPDATE**:

In case you need to make sure the email is the *second* element in the tuple, use this code (see [demo](http://ideone.com/uZPLhs)):

```
lst = re.findall(p, test_str)
print([(tpl[1], tpl[0]) if not tpl[1] else tpl for tpl in lst])
# => [('Mr ABC', 'mr@abc.com'), ('Foo, Bar', 'foo@bar.com'), ('', 'mr@xyz.com')]
```

Comment: That's a beautiful solution but then I forgot to mention that we could also have emails with just the email part like 'mr@xyz.com'. Updated the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please look. Note that the tuples will still be created even if the email part is absent, and the email will be captured into group 1 since they are not inside `<>`.

Comment: In case your output needs to be `[('Mr ABC', 'mr@abc.com'), ('Foo, Bar', 'foo@bar.com'), ('', 'mr@xyz.com')]`, you can use `lst = re.findall(p, test_str) // print([(tpl[1], tpl[0]) if not tpl[1] else tpl for tpl in lst])`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [`getaddresses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.getaddresses) for that:

```
emails = getaddresses('"Mr ABC" <mr@abc.com>, "Foo, Bar" <foo@bar.com>, "mr@xyz.com"')

=> [('Mr ABC', 'mr@abc.com'), ('Foo, Bar', 'foo@bar.com'), ('', 'mr@xyz.com')]
```

Comment: This works great, except you need to pass a list to getaddresses: emails = getaddresses(["Mr ABC" <mr@abc.com>, "Foo, Bar" <foo@bar.com>, "mr@xyz.com"]) --> [('Mr ABC', 'mr@abc.com'), ('Foo, Bar', 'foo@bar.com'), ('', 'mr@xyz.com')]